# How to integrate iCloud on a non Document-based app?

Tags: ios, icloud, foundation

I've read the Apple docs and Ray Wenderlich's tutorial. It seems that I'm forced to use UIDocument so I read it up in the docs. I've found that it's effective to use Document-based approach.

My problem is I don't want to be tied in techniques specific to the platform (iOS) thus my app has its own models made from scratch that only inherit from NSObject. This includes saving/loading.

Now, I need to integrate iCloud along with my old models. How will I do it in an elegant/effective way where I get to keep my old model implementation and be able to integrate iCloud?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not in any way forced to use `UIDocument`. You can use iCloud via `NSFileManager` and `NSMetadataQuery`. The general approach is:

#### When creating files

- Create the file locally, as normal without iCloud
- Use `-[NSFileManager setUbiquitous:itemAtURL:destinationURL:error:]` to transfer the file to iCloud storage.
- (if necessary) Check on upload progress using `NSMetadataQuery` or by polling URL resource values.

#### When opening files

- Use `NSMetadataQuery` to locate iCloud-resident files
- Use `-[NSFileManager startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:error:]` to begin download or to synchronize the local copy with the cloud copy.
- Check on upload progress using `NSMetadataQuery` or by polling URL resource values with `[NSURL resourceValuesForKeys:]`.

#### When editing files

- Use `NSFileCoordinator` to coordinate your file access with the ubiquity daemon.
- Use `NSFilePresenter` to get notifications of changes to files.

This is all covered in sessions from WWDC 2012 (and maybe 2011, I don't recall), and the classes and methods you'll need are all in the iOS documentation.

Comment: Excuse me.  So you can save and then retrieve not just a UIDocument file but also .txt file across different devices with a common ubiquity container?

Comment: Any file. `UIDocument` is a convenience, but is not required.