# Access/Use iCloud Data of existing iOS App from a Mac OS App

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, icloud, nsdocument

I am working an Mac OS version of an existing  iOS App. The iOS App uses iCloud to share its data accross devices. Of  course this data should be accessable from the Mac OS version as well.  When implementing the iCloud functionality in the iOS App the Stanford  videos have been a great help. The iOS App uses a UIManagedDocument to  setup the Core Data stack and handle all the iCloud related stuff.

Unfurtunatly  there is no "UIManagedDocument class for Mac OS" wich does the same  thing. NSPersistantDocument integrates the Core Data framework but is  not designed to work with iCloud. Thus I am not sure how I can  access/use the UIManagedDocument data in iCloud from within the Mac OS  App.

Access to iCloud from within the Mac OS App is no  problem. After using URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier: I can access  the "iCloud Folder" and see all data wich is stored there. But seeing  and using the data are two different things.

Is there any example that demonstrates to how use iCloud from iOS AND Mac OS?

Thank you very much!e

Comment: This answer is probably relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631294/how-to-integrate-icloud-on-a-non-document-based-app/15642556#15642556

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I know that using I am not forced to use UIManagedDocumen on the iOS side. But it makes things a little less complicated and (what is more important) this is solution is already up and running. Since iCloud is quite fragile I would like to avoid any changes to the current (running) implementation. Thus the first thing I am looking for is a solution to access the UIManagedDocument data send from the iOS app to iCloud from an Mac OS app. Only if anything else fails I would have to use an other solution. Any hint how to use the existing solution from Mac OS?