# iCloud Implementation - upload text file from document directory to icloud

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, icloud

I am new in ios developement .I have created a new appID and enabled iCloud on iTunes Connect.I have enabled entitlements within the app from the summary section. I have included this code for checking for iCloud availability:

```
NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
               URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
if (ubiq) {
    NSLog(@"iCloud access at %@", ubiq);
    // TODO: Load document... 
} else {
    NSLog(@"No iCloud access");
}
```

i am getting iCloud access at something from nslog.

```
-(NSString *)getDocumentPath{
    NSString * string = @"This is a Sample Text File";
    NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Sample.txt"];
    [string writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
 return filePath;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to upload file from document directory to icloud?

Comment: See my previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631294/how-to-integrate-icloud-on-a-non-document-based-app/15642556#15642556